# Mapping complex DTOs to entities with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

I want to map from

```c#
LDTTicketUploadDTO[] to IEnumerable<LDTTicket>
```

The mappings are created in this method and at the end I map the data.

```c#
public void UploadLDTTickets(LDTTicketUploadDTO[] ticketDTOs)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTTicketUploadDTO, LDTTicket>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTTicketDTO, LDTTicket>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTCustomerDTO, LDTCustomer>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTDeviceDTO, LDTDevice>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTUnitDTO, LDTUnit>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTCommandDTO, LDTCommand>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTCommandParameterDTO, LDTCommandParameter>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTObjectDTO, LDTObject>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTControlFileDTO, LDTControlFile>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTDeviceDTO, LDTDevice>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTLanguageDTO, LDTLanguage>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<LDTObjectBitDTO, LDTObjectBit>();

            var tickets = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LDTTicketUploadDTO>, IEnumerable<LDTTicket>>(ticketDTOs);

           // do something with tickets
        }
```

This is how the DTO´s are structured:

```c#
 public class LDTTicketUploadDTO
     {
            public LDTTicketDTO Ticket { get; set; }
            public LDTDeviceDTO Device { get; set; }
            public LDTCustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
     }



 public enum TicketStatus
    {
        New,
        InProgress,
        Done
    }    

    public class LDTTicketDTO
    {
        public bool UploadNeeded { get; set; }
        public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
        public TicketStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LDTUnitDTO> Units { get; set; }
    }

 public class LDTUnitDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FunctionUnit { get; set; }
        public int FunctionUnitAddress { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public int ZoneUnitAddress { get; set; }
        public string Object { get; set; }
        public int ObjectAddress { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LDTCommandDTO> Commands { get; set; }
    }

and more...
```

**What works** is that these properties are correctly mapped to their counterpart entities:

```c#
public LDTDeviceDTO Device { get; set; }
public LDTCustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
```

**What works NOT** is that this property is not mapped:

```c#
  public LDTTicketDTO Ticket { get; set; }
```

This is how the Entities are structured:

```c#
public class LDTTicket
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [Required]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [Required]
        public string TicketNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }

        public TicketStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public bool UploadNeeded { get; set; }

        public virtual LDTCustomer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual LDTDevice Device { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LDTUnit> Units { get; set; }
    }
```

**ONLY** the **Customer** and **Device** property are mapped in the **LDTTicket**

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: One small nitpick - you only need to call CreateMap once per AppDomain, not every single method call here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expecting to populate a LDTTicket sub-property on the ticket, not the matching properties of the ticket itself.  Create direct mappings onto the ticket from the `Ticket` subproperty of the source directly onto the matching properties of the destination.  NOTE: You only need to define your mappings once, not per method execution. Mappings should be defined at app start up and thereafter used.

```
public void UploadLDTTickets(LDTTicketUploadDTO[] ticketDTOs)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<LDTTicketUploadDTO, LDTTicket>();
          .ForMember(d => d.SerialNumber, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Ticket.SerialNumber))
              ...
    //Mapper.CreateMap<LDTTicketDTO, LDTTicket>(); You don't need this
    Mapper.CreateMap<LDTCustomerDTO, LDTCustomer>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<LDTDeviceDTO, LDTDevice>();

    ...
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, yes, or you could change your DTO so that it contains the ticket properties directly instead of within a LDTTicketDTO subproperty.